# How to display tabbar in whole app in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am creating an application. In this I need to display a TabBar in all Activities. I set the TabBar bottom using 4 tabs; `home, contact, about and call us`.
Inside home tab I have some buttons. When I click inside home any button that time I need to move some other Activity. Using intent I moved to another Activity but here the TabBar was not displayed. However, I need to display the same TabBar in all Activities. If any one knows how to do this, please suggest a solution to me.

```
       DefenceLaywer.java:
        public class DefenceLaywer extends TabActivity {

      TabHost tabhost;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tabhost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabhost.newTabSpec("Home");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabhost.newTabSpec("Claimonline");
         TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabhost.newTabSpec("CallUs");
         TabSpec fourthTabSpec = tabhost.newTabSpec("AboutUs");

//        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabhost.newTabSpec("Interactive");
         firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
         secondTabSpec.setIndicator("ContactUs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contactus));
        thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("CallUs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.callus));
       fourthTabSpec.setIndicator("AboutUs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aboutus));



        firstTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,HomeTab.class));
        secondTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,ContactUs.class));
        thirdTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,CallUs.class));
        fourthTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,AboutUs.class));




                tabhost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
                tabhost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
                tabhost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
                tabhost.addTab(fourthTabSpec);       
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

use fragments in activity and set that activity on tabspecs.

To learn FrAgment use following lin:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

and for how to use fragments to implement tab, follow followig tutorial:

http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

Comment: i dnt know how to use fragments.plese suggest me some advice how to use fragment concept in  android